# Java encoding on unix

Tags: java, unix, encoding

I'm working on a java restfull API, when I try to get a file named with accented characters from windows it works just fine, but when I try to do the same thing on unix it doesn't work, I get FileNotFoundException, however the file exists and it's printed correctly on my terminal when i tape ls -l on my folder, when I restarted my java application it surprisingly worked, but within a few days I had the same problem again.

**This is the code I'm using to get my file.**

```
FileInputStream result = null;
Path resourcePath = Paths.get(mypath);
try {
    result = new FileInputStream(resourcePath.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new NoSuchFileException("Unable to find specified resource : " + resourcePath.toString());
}
return result;
```

I start my java application with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 option and my $LANG variable is *en_US.UTF-8*, can you please enlighten me a little here.

Here is a snippet of my exception trace :

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Unable to find specified resource : /home/iriscmsadm/var/data/libraries/whole/help/PARPHO/têteéà.g2t
        at com.afp.iris.sr.commons.service.FilesManager.getFileContent(FilesManager.java:422) ~[iris-sr-commons-filesmanager-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at com.afp.iris.sr.cms.library.application.LibraryApplicationRoot.getResource(LibraryApplicationRoot.java:436) ~[iris-sr-cms-library-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442) [jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
```

Comment: It's for sure not a permission problem!

Comment: Ah, you said file that *contains* accented characters, not one that was *named* with accented characters... That's a different matter. What is your `$LC_CTYPE` when you are in a console where you can see the file name properly?

Comment: Sorry ! Yeah that's what I meant to say, a file that's named with accented characters, when I try echo $LC_CTYPE i get nothing can I check it otherwise.

Comment: What JVM exactly are you using? Do a java -version. The `-Dfile.encoding `argument is Sun JVM specific.  Linux machines either come with GNU JVM or OpenJDK's JVM therefore this might not work

Comment: Well, what about the message from the original `FileNotFoundException`? If you add it as the `cause` of your `NoSuchFileException`  you may see it in the stack trace.

Comment: My JVM version is 1.7.0_76.